# Recalling poultry known to have Salmonella

Tags: food-safety, poultry

In the recent news, there was 91k pounds of turkey recalled because it was known to contain Salmonella,  If I've always been told to cook my poultry to full doneness to kill off Salmonella and other baddies, so why is meat often recalled if its known to have Salmonella?

I always treat each step in the prep and cooking as if it could make me sick, so it seems like a waste of 6000 or so turkeys when the meat can easily be cooked safe to eat.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have good food safety practices but not everyone does, and mistakes happen. A hurried food service worker accidentally cross-contaminating some food could be deadly to someone with a weak immune system, or make someone with a strong immune system very ill (I've been there - awful!). Recalling the food reduces the risks from mistakes.